# R Version Compatibility

Tags: r, package

Are different versions of `R` that all belong to `3.1` compatible with respect to packages?

That is, **under windows**,

- do all these versions have the same base packages installed in the library?
- does `3.1.0` work with package binaries compiled for `3.1.1` etc?

Comment: I think so ... probably discussed somewhere in the "R extensions" manual.

Comment: Theoretically they should but I don't believe there is anything stopping a package author from specifying "R >= 3.1.1" as a requirement of their package which would mean that you could install the package with 3.1.1 but not 3.1.0.  Base packages wouldn't do this though.

Comment: For example look at [devtools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) right now.  It depends on R (>= 3.0.2).

Comment: @Dason I see. Is there any way to call/check this within `R`?

Comment: Check what exactly? Attempting to install it should tell you whether you can install it or not ;)

Comment: @Dason here's the thing, I prepare the binaries today (from the wrong `3.1.1` version. Tomorrow, Ill have the once-in-a-year chance of accessing some remote server, and any (not base) package that I want to be working there I need to have installed there in advance. So if this is going to be an issue, I'd rather know today - when I cannot attempt to install.

Comment: And I assume by *attempt to install* you mean *Attempt to require/load*

Comment: Shouldn't matter should it?  If there is the issue I mentioned where you don't have the specific version of R required then it won't let you install it.  I mean there might be issues where you can install stuff but it won't load properly but that would be due to something other than what we're talking about now.   And what do you mean by "the wrong 3.1.1 version"

Comment: I see, I meant wrong (different) `3.1` version. I think I'm fine and Im just panicking due to bad experiences today.